# How the class or id field in HTML of Gmail and Quora generated and why?

Tags: html, css, gmail

In Gmail:

```
<tr class="zA yO" id=":1t4">
```

In Quora:

```
<span id="ld_zpQ1Cb_27965">
```

What is the intention and what tool they use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that they are using tools which generate obfuscate the code. I thing they might be using some high level programming language to generate the html code. If you look to the source code which is generated by asp.net you will also encounter generated ids.